# Let $(G, *)$be a group. If an element $a \in G$ commutes with an element $x \in G$, then show that $a^{-1}$ also commutes with $x$.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

When the theory of groups is built up from its axioms, it is often necessary to establish very simple results such as

$ax = xa \Longrightarrow a^{-1}x = xa^{-1}. \tag 1$

Thus we ask how the title question might be proved.

Comment: What have you tried ? What does it mean "to commute" in this context ?

Comment: I edited your question to properly $\LaTeX$ify it, and also to add some background and context.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in G$ such that $ax = xa$ for all $x \in G$. Then multiplying by the inverse of $a$ (which exists, why?) on both sides from the left and right, we get that 
$$xa^{-1} = a^{-1}x,$$
where $a^{-1}$ denotes the inverse to $a$ in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

We denote the identity element of $G$ by $e$.

If

$ax = xa, \tag 1$

then

$x = ex = (a^{-1}a)x = a^{-1}(ax) = a^{-1}(xa) = (a^{-1}x)a, \tag 2$

so

$xa^{-1} = (a^{-1}x)aa^{-1} = (a^{-1}x)e = a^{-1}x; \tag 3$

that is, $a^{-1}$ commutes with $x$.